# How can I list workloads in my GKE cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have a GKE cluster in my project with several workloads.
How can I list all or search for a specific workload without using the GCP console GUI?
My goal is simple: a programmatical way (api/sdk/gcloud) to find if a workload called `xpto` exists in the cluster or not.

I need to avoid kubectl commands and rather a high level approach.

Answer (score 1):

The data about Workloads, Services, etc. that is displayed in the Google Cloud Console is taken from the Kubernetes API, so it might be able to gather the same by making the appropriate Kubernetes API calls such as Enumerate workloads. You can refer to these Kubernetes API links [1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/ahpi-concepts/) [2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#-strong-workloads-apis-strong-)

As the [Google Kubernetes Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest) and gcloud CLI is primarily for configuring your cluster on Google Cloud. This might include tasks such as:

- Creating a cluster.
- Deleting a cluster.
- Configuring cluster-level networking, such as rotating the cluster control plane IP or enabling network policy enforcement.
- Updating the version of Kubernetes running on the cluster.
- Adding, removing, or modifying node pools in your cluster.
- Setting the machine type or node image used for your cluster's nodes.
- Configuring the geographic zones or regions in which your cluster runs.

Comment: Your link 1 is broken. Did you mean this link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud` is more intended to manage the Cluster Infraestructure rather than managing operations inside it considering that at the end GKE it's another K8s implementation and there are tools to manage that.

Said that, `gcloud` doesn't offer what you ask because it would be like re-inventing the wheel since `kubectl` already does this. In fact the GCP docs don't show a way to list workloads using [`gcloud container clusters`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters)

The way you will check if a "workload" exists will depend on the type of it: a pod, deployment, etc. and using `kubectl`